# Can one Reciting bracha "Mechaye Hameitim" at a friend's wedding

Tags: blessing

I have seen in several Siddurim instructions saying that if one has not seen a close friend for at least 30 days (some instructions said 1 year) s/he should recite *Mechaye Hameitim* which means "Reviving the dead."

Suppose someone has not heard from a very dear friend for more than a year. He then sees the friend at the friend's wedding in a context where he'd generally be obligated in that blessing.

Would it be appropriate to say this bracha at the person's wedding considering that it has a "negative" connotation of referring to the dead?

Comment: DanF do you agree with my edits? Or would an answer be acceptable that says your hypothetical case didn't perfectly exclude prior contact to constitute the 12-month separation period? I just tried to focus your question on the wedding part only, without debating what counts as prior contact.

Comment: @DoubleAA Your edits are fine. Thank you.